# How to get an element by pressing TAB in selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to fill out some personal data on a website. The first input element can be accessed by *find_element_by_id* but the id of the next text field has a different id every time I access the website. In a Browser, I can simply press the TAB key two times to get to the desired text input field. Is there a way to achieve similar behavior with selenium?

i tried the following:

```
input1 = browser.find_element_by_id('id_email')
input1.send_keys("email@something.com")

input2 = browser.send_keys(Keys.TAB).send_keys(Keys.TAB)
input2.send_keys("Something else")
```

But Line 3 gives me:

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Comment: Can you please share your url?  You can identify objects with more than ID and you can find objects in relation to each other. It would be good for your learning if we show you how (so we need the url or the dom).... Alternatively, you can quickly try send keys with the tab key against your input1 object (not the browser). Might not work but that's what you're manually doing when you press tab, you're in the fields first.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send keys against the browser object.
This line:

```
input2 = browser.send_keys(Keys.TAB).send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

is not valid. It even tells you as such:  `'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'`

That says your webdriver object (which you called "browser") does not have a attribute ( a method/ a function) called Send_Keys.

Top tip to avoid this sort of problem is to use a good IDE with intellisense. That will tell you the methods you can use.

In vscode, you get this:

[image: intellisense vs coce]

As you type, it tells you valid commands - and you can see the driver has no send keys!

What you need to do is use `.sendKeys(..)` against a **web element**.

In your code you already have `input1` - that is a web element. You can send keys against that.

Something like this:

```
input1 = browser.find_element_by_id('id_email')
input1.send_keys("email@something.com")
input1.send_keys(Keys.Tab)
```

If you want to do multiple tabs from the same object, you can just add multiple. This will tab 3 times

```
.send_keys(Keys.TAB + Keys.TAB + Keys.TAB)
```

When i run a sample script on google.com,
I tab 3 times i go to the googlesearch button. (first tab is the clear, second tab is the microphone, 3rd tab goes to the button):

[image: google after tabs]

Finally, using tabs to navigate is a LAST RESORT. They can be flaky and inconsistent. You REALLY should get an identifier for your object.
If you can share your URL or the page DOM then I'm help you identify a working identifier. I know you say there is no ID but there many ways to access objects.

Answer (score -1):

welcome!

i can only guess, since i'm not able to test the code out. But seems like you are not getting the right element with the 2 Tabs, since it starts from the start of the html page and not from the input1 field. You'd better getting the password by its id or parents id, rather then with Key.TAB.